# Simplification of REGEX expression

Tags: regex, computer-science, regular-language

I need to prove or disprove the below REGEX

```
(RS + R )* R = R (SR + R)*
// or, for programmers:
/(RS|R)*R/ == /R(SR|R)*/
```

I have a strong gut feel that they are equivalent, but how do i give a step by step proof using the laws of REGEX.

Comment: Yes, they are equivalent. Have you started the proof yet? At what point are you stuck? We will not simply do your homework for you :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First understand what this formal languages mean:

```
(RS + R)*R = R(SR + R)*
```

From LHS, `(RS + R)*`  uses to generate any combinations of `RS` and `R` including `^` epsilon. Some example strings are `{^, RS, RSRS, RRRS, RSR,...}`: strings always starts from `R` but can end with either `S` or `R` - we can describe in English: `R` can appear in any combination where `S` is always followed by one `R` (two consecutive `S` are not possible).

And, complete LHS's re `(RS + R)*R`  means string always terminates with `R`.

Now, consider following examples:

1. `R + S` is same as `S + R`, it is basically union
2. But `RS` can't be written as `SR`, order is important in concatenation
3. `(RS)R` can be written as `R(SR)`
4. `(RS)*R`  can be written as `R(SR)*`, both are same that is `RSRSRS...SR`
5. `(AB + AC)` can be written as `A(B + C)`
6. `(AB + A)` can be written as `A(B + ^)`,  this is because `A = ^A = A^`
7. `(BA + A)` can be written as `(B + ^)A`.

Formal Proof:

> ```c
>    (RS + R)*R      // LHS
> => (R(S + ^))*R    // from rule 6
> => R((S + ^)R)*    // from rule 4
> => R(SR + R)*      // from rule 7, in revers `(B + ^)A` --> `(BA + A)`
> // RHS
> ```

Same steps are correct for regex.

Comment: Thanks for listing the rules before the proof =)).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the first regex is equal to the second.

I cannot give you the formal proof because I am not that well versed in proving, but I can give you a hint that those expressions are equal.

You can enumerate examples manually, like so:

1.) Can I produce e(epsilon)?

- (RS + R)* can be epsilon
- R cannot be epsilon
- concatenate the 2 = (epsilon)R or simply = R

So the most basic string you can form is 'R'. Now continue the process of deriving strings and you'll come up with the conclusion that the 2 regex are equal.